# How to Disable Default WordPress Email Notifications

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I disable following WordPress default email notifications without using a plugin, utilizing functions.php file?

```
            'wp_new_user_notification_to_user' 
            'wp_new_user_notification_to_admin' 
            'wp_notify_postauthor'
            'wp_notify_moderator'
            'wp_password_change_notification'
            'send_password_change_email'
            'send_email_change_email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' );

// DISABLE BOTH default WordPress new user notification emails
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_new_user_notification' ) ) :
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $deprecated = null, $notify = '' ) {
    return;
    }
endif;
```